# How to specify generic constraint: class inherited from interface?

Tags: c#, linq, generics

How to specify that type should be a class inherited from Interface? I tried various variants but no sense.

```
public class CarDal<TCarMark> where TCarMark:class//also tried ICarMark
{
    ...
    private static readonly DataContext Context = new DataContext(ConnectionString);
    private Table<ICarMark> _tblCarMarks = Context.GetTable<TCarMark>();//Error is "Cannot convert source type 'Table<TCarMark> to target type Table<ICarMark>'"
    ...
}
```

Comment: By the way, a static data-context is a really really bad idea

Comment: Ok, I'll take into account, but could you please explain why? (provide link or short comment) Thank you.

Comment: added that to my answer; this **will** cause huge problems

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your constraint, especially combining the two forms you cite, is fine:

```
 where TCarMark : class, ICarMark
```

The problem is variance.

A `Table<TCarMark>` has no covariant/contravariant relationship with a `Table<ICarMark>`

You must use `Table<TCarMark>` throught this class:

```
private Table<TCarMark> _tblCarMarks = Context.GetTable<TCarMark>();
// emphasis: ^^^
```

However! Don't use a static data-context:

- it will not be thread-safe
- it will mean your data-context grows over time (it is meant to be a unit of work, not an application lifetime object)